# Windows Server 2016: Cannot set password

Tags: windows-server-2016

I did a fresh reinstallation of windows server 2016 on my dedicated server remotely (Using IDRAC's virtual console). After the installation, logonui popped up asking to set new password for administrator named user, where i pressed enter key from keyboard.

Then a new screen popped up asking for "New password" & "Confirm password". Now when i've entered password in the field & pressed "Enter" key from keyboard, nothing happened. It's stuck there & i can't enter in the "Confirm password" field.

How can I get past this?

Comment: Have you tried to reopen iDRAC Virtual Console?

Answer (score 5):

It really tooks me a long time to find out how to set the password after the installation.

I've tried several combination, but nothing works.

Finally, I press down the "tab" key without any hope, a miracle happened, the cursor finally moved to the "Confirm password" field!

Hopes it works for you!

Comment: TAB!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Yeahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a second problem where the server would tell me: "the password on this account cannot be changed at this time"

The solution is to wait... and try a couple of minutes later, it will eventually work...